# How to determine the best case and worst case of an program(algorithm)?

Tags: php, algorithm

Suppose I have this program, I want to compare 2 input lists. Assume array A and array B. How do I determine the best case and worst case of the function?

Here is my code in [php]:

```
foreach($array_1 as $k){
    if(!in_array($k, $array_2)){
        array_push($array_2, $k);
    }
}
```

What is the best case and worst case of the for loop? Please include some explaination, thank you :)

EDITED:

Since my goal is to compare 2 lists that have at lists 1 element in common. I think my above code is wrong. Here is the updated of my code

```
foreach($array_1 as $k){
    if(in_array($k, $array_2)){
        array_push($array_3, $k);
    }
}
```

And I guess it would be:

Best case: O(n)

Worst case: O(N*M)

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a quick analysis then:

```
foreach($array_1 as $k)
```

means that the operation within will be repeated for each element of the array. Let denote the size of the array by `N`.

The operation within:

```
if (!in_array($k, $array_2)) {
  array_push($array_2, $k);
}
```

There are 2 operations here:

- `in_array`
- `array_push`

`array_push` is likely to be constant, thus `O(1)`, while `in_array` is more likely a linear search in `array_2` which will take either 1 operation (found as the first element) up to the length of `array_2` operations.

Note that `in_array` represent the only variable here:

- best case: `in_array` returns at the first comparison --> all elements of `array_1` are the same, and either `array_2` was empty or they are equal to its first element. Complexity is `O(N)` since we have `N` elements in `array_1`
- worst case: each time we examine each element of `array_2` --> all elements of `array_1` are distinct and they are distinct from the previous elements of `array_2`. If `M` is the length of `array_2` when it is inputed, then the complexity is along the line of `O(N * (N+M) )`, `(N+M)/2` being the mean time for searching in `array_2` as it's growing from `M` to `M+N` elements and the constant `2` being discarded in the `O` notation

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, the best case is n, worst case big o O(N * (N+M))?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. If `array_2` is empty to begin with, the worst cast is simplified to `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Oh i see.. Thank you Matthiu, Dr Math :) I just cant figure out the worst case hihi..

Comment: @Dr Math: I think my code is wrong. I re-wrote the code. Based on your explanation, i think the best and worst case still the same huh? Am I correct?

Comment: @Matthiue.. can help me clarify? I am trying hard to understand this concept. Please?

Comment: Actually it's slightly better in the worst case (I edited your post to format the code and adjusted the worst case). Since `array_2` does not grow any longer, the cost of looking up in `array_2` is now fix in each iteration of the loop: `O(M)`. Thus the worst case is now `O(N*M)`.

Comment: It's been a little while since I've worked with big O notation, but IIRC, `O(N * (N + M)) == O(N^2)` -- that is, you don't say `O(N*(N+M))`, it doesn't exist.

Comment: The big O notation express complexity for asymptotic behavior depending on input characteristics. If you have two uncorrelated inputs, then it seems logical that big O will be expressed in terms of those two inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation is all about approximations.  It makes it easy to compare algorithms.

If you imagine your array of elements, a search might be order N (you must look at each item to find the item you want), it might be order Log(N) if you have an ordered collection or it could even be order 1 depending on your collection type.

The important thing here is to look at your algorithm and determine what the key operations are that are repeated.

Foreach is clearly an order N operation, by definition you must operate on each element in your list.  O(N)

Next is your if InArray 2.  This sounds like a search over an array, which would most likely be unordered so it would be order N (linear search).  So your complexity would now be O(N * M). (for each n elements in array 1, perform a search of order N complexity over array 2).

Finally you have an array push.  I don't know your environment but this could be order 1 or order N if the array needs to be reallocated and copied in order to grow.  Lets assume order 1 to keep it simple.  Therefore your complexity in Big O is O(N*M).

So now best case is for each element to find it's counterpart on the first try and perform the array push, which would be O(N * 1 * 1) = O(N).

Worst case is that the each element cannot be found in the second list forcing the full search of all elements in array 2.  Therefore complexity is O(N * M).

Your teachers want to understand your thinking so show them your assumptions made.  I highly recommend that you read the exact question and information you have been given before relying on the assumptions given here, you may have been told the language/platform which would tell you the exact penalty and algorithms used in each case. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally with such a problem I just look at the algorithm as Dr. Evil and ask, "How can I make this take the **most** time possible?"

Comment: Do you have better algorithm for this? Okay, my goal is compare 2 lists that have at least 1 element in common. Any idea Dr Evil :) :)

Comment: Well, its tough to say without knowing more information than you provided. From what I see, Dr. Evil would try to feed you input where every single input is in `array_2`. If Dr. Evil had a chance to know how `in_array` and `array_push` are implemented, he could do even more evil to you.